# How to get an item from an item collection in Amazon's Dynamo Ruby SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services

I've been straining to figure this out, it seems like it should be very simple but this scenario is not [documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html) well, if its possible.

Using the [aws-ruby-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby) as my interface, I need to get a single Item from an ItemCollection without iterating over every Item in the collection.  So `table.items.select(:id => 5)` would do it, however that only gives you the attributes you select.

Let's say I have a table with 15 attributes, and I want all of them, why should I have to provide all of the attributes to get them?  Makes me really appreciate how nice Active Record is...

I figured out that I can do this and it does work but this is so ugly, I almost hate putting it in here, much less my code.

```
item = nil
table.items.each {|i| item = i if i[:id] == 5 }
```

How might I get all of the attributes of an item from the collection *without enumerating*?

EDIT

Here are other methods I've tried to no avail.

```
table.items.query("slug" => "test-item")
*** ArgumentError Exception: a hash key value is required

table.items.query({"slug" => "test-item"})
*** ArgumentError Exception: a hash key value is required

table.items.query(Hash["slug", "test-item"])
*** ArgumentError Exception: a hash key value is required

table.items['slug-test-item'].attributes.count
0
```

Here is proof the item exists "test-item" is the slug and composite key (pk):
[image]

Second EDIT
Now that I realize that "hash_value" is the literal key I must use, and that it searches from the composite key, here's what I get:

```
(rdb:1) table.items.query(:hash_value => "test-item")
#<Enumerator: <AWS::DynamoDB::ItemCollection>:each({:query=>true, :hash_key_value=>{:s=>"test-item"}})>

(rdb:1) table.items.query(:hash_value => "test-item").each(&:title)
*** AWS::DynamoDB::Errors::ValidationException Exception: Query can be performed only on a table with a HASH,RANGE key schema
```

Comment: Am I not giving a valid key value?  Is this a bug in the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was that the hash-key-value is actually the primary key (composite key).  So the following works.

```
(rdb:1) table.items['test-item'].attributes['title']
"Test"
```

`test-item` is my pk.

Comment: That makes sense in light of a hash key value store.  The example of 'hash-key-value' was confusing. `table.items['primary-key']` would've been clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is slightly confusing.
Dynamo is a Key-Value store so usage is similar to `Hash`.

From [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html):

```
# gets a reference to the item, no request is made
item = table.items['hash-key-value']
```

Perhaps `#query` fits your use-case?

```
# find all items with a given hash key value
items.query(:hash_value => "abc123").each(&:foo)
```

Comment: Please see my edit, I've tried that, the documentation is poor on that, nor does the link you provided directly address any of your examples.  Forgive my frustration, but this is harder than it should be.  Hopefully that clears up any confusion from my question.  Let me know, thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, my examples are indeed a valid key value store.

Comment: I gave it a +1 for mentioning query, though I had already tried it. The missing link was that my composite key was the hash key to use.  I was confused by the terminology.